# Pass PySNMP getCmd an array of ObjectTypes

Tags: python, pysnmp

I'm trying to leverage PySNMP for a monitoring system, but I want to pass it a dynamic list of objects to query per connection made, like below:

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
        getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData(self.device.getSNMPCommunity(), mpModel=0),
           UdpTransportTarget((self.device.getHost(), 
self.device.getSNMPPort()),self.device.getSNMPTimeout(),int(1)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', 0)),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysUpTime', 0)),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysLocation', 0)),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysContact', 0)),
        )
    )
```

Instead, I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
for sensor in self.sensors:
        if(sensor.sensor_type == 'snmp'):
            if(sensor.snmp_oid):
                Sensors.append(ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(sensor.snmp_oid)))
            else:
                Sensors.append(
                    ObjectType(
                        ObjectIdentity(
                            sensor.snmp_mib,
                            sensor.snmp_object,
                            sensor.snmp_field
                     ).addAsn1MibSource('file:///usr/share/snmp/mibs')))
```

And then call

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
        getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
            CommunityData(device_to_proc.snmp_community, mpModel=0),
            UdpTransportTarget((device_to_proc.host, int(device_to_proc.snmp_port)),int(device_to_proc.snmp_timeout),int(1)),
            ContextData(),
            Sensors
        )
    )
```

Is there a different function of pysnmp that I'm missing, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that what you need is just an asterisk `*` to unpack the sequence of objects you gathered into the SNMP GET function varargs:

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData(device_to_proc.snmp_community, mpModel=0),
           UdpTransportTarget((device_to_proc.host, int(device_to_proc.snmp_port)),int(device_to_proc.snmp_timeout),int(1)),
           ContextData(),
           *Sensors
    )
)
```

As a side note, keep in mind that while there is no explicit limit on the number of OIDs you can send towards your SNMP agent, some agents may choke and/or refuse to serve too many objects within a single SNMP query.

Comment: Wow, I'm obviously a Python noob, that did the trick! Amazing, thank you.